# JavaScript running on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This JS is running on my page load and I don't want it to. I thought it should wait for change of ddlEquipment but it isn't. On top of that selectedID4 should be null at page load so it shouldn't run the if. Does anyone know how I can stop this?

```
$("#ddlEquipment").change(function() {

  var selectedid = $('#ddlSubDepartments option:selected').val();
  var selectedid2 = $('#ddlDepartments option:selected').val();
  var selectedid3 = $('#ddlMachines option:selected').val();
  var selectedid4 = $('#ddlEquipment option:selected').val();

  alert("test");
  if (selectedid4 != null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Problem/PopulateProblemsddl",
        data: {
          id: selectedid,
          id2: selectedid2,
          id3: selectedid3,
          id4: selectedid4
        },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(result);
          var s = '<th></th>';

          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            s += '<th>'
            result[i].value '</th>';

          }
          console.log(s);

          $('#NameOfProblem').html(s);


        });
    }
    else {
      alert("this is else");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you function into

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  $("#ddlEquipment").change(function () {
    // rest of your code
  }
});
```